# Jquery - How to loop this slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, repeat

So I've been working on a slider and I don't really know how to make it repeat itself. So far I've only listed 10 slides but in the end I'll have around 20.

Here's a link to a JS fiddle so you can see what I've got so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/sth23e2w/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //settings for slider
  var width = 360;
  var animationSpeed = 1000;
  var pause = 3000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  //cache DOM elements
  var $slider = $(".characters");
  var $slideContainer = $(".slide-characters", $slider);
  var $slides = $(".char-avatar", $slider);

$(".right-slide").click(function() {
    $slideContainer.animate(
      { "margin-left": "+=" + width },
      animationSpeed,
      function() {
        if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
          currentSlide = 1;
          $slideContainer.css("margin-left", 0);
        }
      }
    );
  });
  $(".left-slide").click(function() {
    $slideContainer.animate(
      { "margin-left": "-=" + width },
      animationSpeed,
      function() {
        if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
          currentSlide = 1;
          $slideContainer.css("margin-left", 0);
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Or if you really want you could check out the live version I've got over at Codepen: https://codepen.io/Crownedpride/project/editor/ZmbqRv/

If you want to know what it's going to be used for:
I'm currently writing a fantasy novel which I've got an artist drawing characters for. I want to display those characters on my own website via that setup I've made. There's roughly going to be 20 different characters that he'going to draw for me, although later there might be more depending if there'll be a Volume 2.

I'm looking forward to your replies.

ps: I'm really new to Jquery/js so please go easy on me >_<

Comment: You can use this `https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html`

Comment: @NiravJoshi I'm assuming I should just use the loop:true; setting if I were to use that?